# What equation does this graph represent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Can you name it?

[image: Mystery Graph]

The answer is very simple, in fact.

Comment: Yes, this is a challenge

Comment: Looks like $1-\sqrt{\text{some trig with period }2\pi}$

Comment: It is a mustache.

Comment: is it a word puzzle? or is it just a matter of finding a function?

Comment: Its the Lyft graph.

Comment: There's no word puzzle here, it's just a very simple arrangement that few people ever use. HINT: There is a very similar equation in the "suggested" bar.

Comment: @SimpleArt And that is why he mustache us about it

Comment: Say, if we figure out what the function is without a "name" attached, does that count?

Comment: Definitely, if there is a special name for this, I don't know it

Comment: A graph is something associated with a function, not an equation.

Comment: Looks to be approximately $f(\theta) = 1 - \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{\sin\theta} \cos^{2}\theta = 1 - \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{\sin\theta} (1 - \sin^{2}\theta)$ on its natural domain, but that hardly seems simple enough to be a riddle answer.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang That is really impressive. The intervals are exactly correct, but the curves are SLIGHTLY off. You are correct that the answer I'm looking for is simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear to be the graph of $$y=(\sin x)^{(\sin x)}$$

When plotted by desmos.com, we get this shape, but Wolfram Alpha has other ideas it seems.

Comment: Congratulations sir!

Comment: Thanks @tphilli...I was trying to upload the image from desmos.com, but failed miserably. I am intrigued to know why the Wolfram Alpha version is different.

Comment: It's a very unconventional equation, so I'm not surprised the graphs are different. I didn't actually know Wolfram Alpha had a different version. I got mine using Grapher. Maybe this warrants a question of it's own? haha

Comment: I figured it out! In the top-right corner of the Plots section, you need to change the graph from "complex-valued plot" to "real-valued plot". I never even realized that was there. I wonder what the difference is..?

Comment: Oh yes, I see that. It seems that the complex valued outputs are just excluded altogether

Comment: Nice answer (+1). $$y=(\sin x)^{(\sin x)^{(\sin x)^{(\sin x)}}}$$ has a similar shape but with sharper turns. Also, $y=(\cos x)^{(\cos x)}$ is similar and symmetrical about the $y$-axis.

Comment: Much obliged @hypergeometric. Note that $f(\sin x)$ and $f(\cos x)$ are lateral translations of each other.